# Custom field type Document Information panel is not getting loaded

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom field type as a dropdownlist which displays the no. of users from the web site. Now I have a document library with this custom field type. When I tries to create a item it opens the MS Word instance and it gives a message as Document Information Panel is unable to load.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.
Tejas jagtap

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error through a quite different path, but I think it is likely this solution will fix yours as well.

---

### How the problem manifested for me:

- Open Word 2007.
- Load any document.
- Open file properties (File > Prepare > Properties).

At that point I received a message "The document information panel was unable to load."

---

### The fix:

Copy **IPEDINTL.DLL**
from **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Designer Tools\Office12\1033**
to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033**

---

### Comments:

This is apparently a file associated with InfoPath (which I did not install when I installed Office 2007) yet it strangely fixes this issue with Word (and apparently Excel from what I have read).

By the way, the credit for the fix goes to [Tom Van Gaever](http://www.tomvangaever.be/blog/index.php?entry=entry090217-180330); I am just the messenger here.

**2010.03.10 Update**

I confirmed that this defect manifests by not installing InfoPath in the Office 2007 bundle: on a separate machine where InfoPath was installed the error did not occur.